# Does Paw app support OIDC Authorization_code flow with support. of PKCE

Tags: paw-app

I am trying to establinsh an OAuth 2.0 Auhorization code flow with PKCE support from Okta provider.

I try to set it up with the support of the built-in OAuth 2.0 support with advanced options but I don't find a way to tell the get access token request to use the "code" provided by the 'authorize' request did just before

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thanks
Olivier

Comment: I also looked for this but seems like it's not supported. I only was able to get it working on Postman.